# Image view in table cell has height constraint with priority 1000 but image is squashed

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard

I've got constraints for a table view cell as follows (the majority are XCode's suggested constraints).

[image]

But when the code is executed the row height of the cell is about half of what it is in the canvas.
Initially I didn't have an aspect ratio constraint and the bottom half of the image was missing when the view controller runs, after adding an aspect ratio constraint instead the image is squashed.

[image]

I don't understand why this is happening. Why when the height of the image view constraint has priority 1000 is it being ignored?

Comment: what is the contentMode on the imageView ?  HAve you tried setting to AsepctFit?

Comment: You should have a log message in your console explaining that your constraints could not be satisfied and the autolayout engine had to pick one to break (your image view height constraint).  It looks like the row height of your tableview is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the height of the cell in

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50;
}
```

like that it's look like you are not set the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` so that it tooks the default hight of 44

Comment: That is it indeed. Actually I hadn't forgotton about this method, I'd assumed if there were constraints in the storyboard it would use them. Seems like an omission to me, this function ought to take the storyboard/constraint value if supplied rather then the default height.

Comment: If you set your row height to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` it will calculate it based on the constraints